# count a field in table until a given value

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to count the number of wins in the win_loose field until "loose" is reached and then stop counting and display the number.  I have this but it counts all wins.

```
$item_count = "SELECT SUM(if(win_loose='win',1,0)) AS user_wins FROM weekpicks";
$item_result = @mysql_query($item_count) or die(mysql_error());
$playerwins = @mysql_result($item_result,0,"user_wins");
echo "$playerwins";
```

Comment: Please, before anything else, stop using MySQL, switch to PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

i can't test just now but think that using variables may be a good aproach

```
SELECT SUM(@n := if(@n and (win_loose='win'),1,0)) AS user_wins 
  FROM weekpicks
    cross join
       (select @n := 1) n
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error "Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING on line 3"

Comment: Splash58, thank you for you input, I ended up getting my result in a different way.